# want to use single quotes by using prettier code formatter VS CODE

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I have downloaded prettier from the extensions on visual studio code  and I would want to use single quotes instead of double quotes please help

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the configuration doc](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

```
// prettier.config.js or .prettierrc.js
module.exports = {
  trailingComma: "es5",
  tabWidth: 4,
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: true, //what you want
};
```

Edit: or you can simply go to the extension settings and search for `prettier.singleQuote`.